Load local CDF files located in any folder and employ the functions given in PYSPEDAS to do further analysis
I am trying to learn data analysis through PYSPEDAS. This article outlines the many salient features of PYSPEDAS and has given some examples as to how to proceed it (see also the supplementary materials). I can reproduce the all the plots given in the paper, with slight modifications to suit my needs.
Whenever I execute the programs, what it does is that it downloads the CDF files of the day in question from internet and stores these files in nested folders where the program is located, like this:

Here is the snippet of the code that does this:
import pyspedas
from pytplot import tplot, get_data, store_data, options, ylim, zlim, tplot_options, tplot_names
import numpy as np
trange = ['2015-10-16/00:30', '2015-10-16/3:00'];
sc = '4';scm_data_rate = 'srvy';scm_datatype='scsrvy'
pyspedas.mms.scm(probe=sc,datatype=scm_datatype,
                     level='l2',trange=trange,
                     data_rate=scm_data_rate,time_clip=True)
tplot_names()
tplot('mms4_scm_acb_gse_scsrvy_srvy_l2',display=True)

tplot_names() will give you the variables available for data manipulation. So, even if there is no internet connection, if we have already downloaded the files and is in this nested folder, then there is no issue (this is what I understand).
Here is my silly question: Let us say that I have a cdf file which is located elsewhere. How do I load this file to do further analysis?
I tried it with help of code that was at here:
from spacepy import pycdf
from pytplot import tplot, get_data, store_data, options, ylim, zlim, tplot_options, tplot_names
cdf1 = pycdf.CDF(r'D:\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\Dir4\cdf_name.cdf')
print(cdf1)

When I do so, the I can see the individual variables, but since tplot_names() does not give anything, I cannot plot it. I tried with the code given here:
from spacepy import pycdf
from pytplot import tplot, get_data, store_data, options, ylim, zlim, tplot_options, tplot_names
cdf2 = pycdf.CDF('D:/Dir1/Dir2/Dir3/Dir4/cdf_name.cdf')
print(cdf2)

and
import cdflib
from spacepy import pycdf
from pytplot import tplot, get_data, store_data, options, ylim, zlim, tplot_options, tplot_names
cdf3 = cdflib.CDF('D:/Dir1/Dir2/Dir3/Dir4/cdf_name.cdf')
print(cdf3)

Hence, in short my question is: how to load local CDF files located in any folder and employ the functions given in PYSPEDAS to do further analysis?
I am using Python 3.11.4 in Windows 11. And only using IDLE and no other python distibution such as Anaconda or similar one.
